# How to determine(with some confidence) if two extremely long lists of numbers (terabytes) are similar?

Tags: algorithms, comparison

I have two very large files with numbers seperated by commas. What is most efficient/fastest way to say with some confidence that these two files have same numbers.

The main rule if if two distributions are the same, also the order of data does matter for example:
**A = {1 2 4 5 6}**
**B = {6 5 4 2 1}**
**C = {0.5 0.5 1 2 3 4 5 6}**

in above case A and C are still similar but A and B are totally different

To be more clear lets split the question into 3 main tasks

1. Given large lists A,B find if lets say 50% of A is contained in B (Most efficient technique without comparing all numbers from list)
2. Given A,B match above condition check that the overlapping numbers have similar order as mentioned above i.e. if 2 in A is followed by 1 same should happen in B. The positions of 1,2 can be different in B.
3. Select two independent batches from A and B and test if those are from Poission distribution, binomial distribution.

Comment: If you expect that the files are equal bit for bit, you can compute a hash, say [SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum). If the hash is equal you can be reasonably sure that the files are equal. *Similarity* as implied by your title is much more difficult.

Comment: You need to specify more precisely what "similar" means. Community votes, please: unclear?

Comment: There is a big problem, without definition of similarity, when you say that order does matter and at the same time you want answer with some confidence, there is no way to know how to handle [6,1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6] - similar to me. To say similar with confidence - do you give e.g. 10% as input (this much it might deviate) or expect this as result - files are similar with 10% margin?

Comment: 1) is doable, 2) is vague but looks like some kind of predictive packing, 3) looks like different question unless you are sure that samples are only from two distributions given, the 50% overlap is the discarded part and this makes your similarity test working. Let me try to tell you possible outcome to see what part of question is missing. 1) the result says 64.6% overlap, 2) 39% of numbers successors from A match those of B. 3) for A both are YES, for B both are NO. Or perhaps you have some results from $\chi^2$? How do you merge results into one conclusive test?

Comment: The whole idea is give a weightage to these three tests (or any other in future). like score = c1*(test1 score)+c2*(test2 score) + c3*(test 3 score) and use supervised machine learning on calculating value of c1,c2,c3. I can take care of ml part but need some statistical/algorithms for the test computations. Some vague ideas also works, give me hints to jump on :)

Comment: For more context the whole problem is related to numerical data flow. What the final goal is to estimate with some confidence if some numerical data is flowing from one file to another file. Since the most data flow system is batch based let say a batch of thousand ( we would be able to find a match with A and B while C is required for data transformation, which is let say if A = 1 ,2 ,3 and B = A+3, i.e. 4,5,6 comparison distribution will help with this.  Now on our supervised ML we can tune up or provide conditional c1,c2,c3 to help us getting better result. Hop it clarifies further

Comment: Your question is statistical (indeed, you included the phrase "with some confidence"). Accordingly, to give an answer which is meaningful, you probably want to be comparing (at least) two models for how the sequences were generated - e.g. $H_0$ is "one sequence was generated from the other by taking half of the terms and interspersing random terms" vs $H_1$ is "both sequences were generated independently by [insert random process]." That level of specificity will also help determine the "right" comparison algorithm.

Comment: As a suggestion, a count-min sketch might be a good similarity measure.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jaccard Similarity, as it gives a measure of set similarity.  See MinHash, locality sensitive hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Anwser is hashing.

- Lists are small enough to fit in memory, are unsorted and
  scanning through them completely with a single machine counts as
  quick, then the idea of building a hash set out of the smaller list
  and then scan the larger for matches.
- One of the lists is small enough to fit in memory and you need to
  use more than one compute to make scanning the larger list fast
  enough, then scanning the small list on all machines or scanning on
  one and passing the hash set around will allow you some speedup.
- If the small list is too large, then building partial hash sets on
  many machines can work.  Distribute the hash sets according to some
  modulo method.  Each machine would then read part of the bigger list
  and send the list element according to the same hash modulo method
  the first list hashes were distributed.

[MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) will help you in this journey too.

Breakthrough achievements:

[Google Teams With Prodigal Son to Bust Data Sort Record](http://Google%20Teams%20With%20Prodigal%20Son%20to%20Bust%20Data%20Sort%20Record)

[Breaking the Minute Barrier for TeraSort](https://www.wired.com/insights/2012/11/breaking-the-minute-barrier-for-terasort/)